# Problemas para desplegar con github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

Últimamente estuve haciendo un par de proyectos para sumar a mi CV y con todos no tuve ningún problema para subirlo a Github pages.

Sin embargo, por algún motivo, el que quiero subir ahora me termina quedando página en blanco y no logro encontrar donde estoy fallando.

Si alguno me puede dar una mano se agradecería.

```
{
  "name": "react-responsive",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://ltrucco.github.io/WebResponsive/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Ese es mi `package.json`, y éste es el repositorio:

- https://github.com/ltrucco/WebResponsive/tree/master

Básicamente estoy corriendo "yarn deploy", y enviando los cambios a git, pero por algún motivo la página sigue en blanco:

- https://ltrucco.github.io/WebResponsive/

EDICIÓN: También probé usando como página inicial https://ltrucco.github.io/WebResponsive sin la barra del final. La página es solo ReactJS, no se conecta con ningún motor (backend).

Comment: ¿Hola, que error te genera? ¿Algún log o en la propia consola te muestra algo, ya sea una advertencia, error o matiz? Recuerda que, si es una app con backend (base de datos y transacciones) GitHub Pages no te permite desplegarla. Debes pasar por Heroku.

Comment: @EdgarGc no arroja ningun error, simplemente la pagina termina figurando en blanco. El build lo hace tambien sin ningun problema

Comment: @LucioTrucco, yo no gasto mi tiempo, yo soy un profesional, y como usuario un poco más avanzado que tu en la comunidad, y dado los privilegios de moderación que he ganado con mi esfuerzo respondiendo preguntas, es mi deber y el de cualquier otro usuario que sepa mas que tu como funciona la comunidad, hacer que las preguntas queden lo mejor redactadas posible para que cualquiera, en cualquier lugar del mundo pueda entender, cuando haces una pregunta aquí, la pregunta ya no es solo tuya, es de todos y a cualquiera le puede ser útil, vamos que no tienes que tomarte las cosas tan a la tremenda

Answer (score 0):

Logre encontrar el problema y es debido a una distinta version de react-router-dom.

Si alguno esta teniendo el mismo problema y tiene una version > 4.0.0, puede agregar la propiedad basename a su BrowserRouter para poder solucionarlo.

En mi caso quedo:

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages';
import SigninPage from './pages/signin';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div >
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/signin" component={SigninPage} exact />
        </Switch>
        
      </Router>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Saludos!